# display base64 image on canvas using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, google-chrome-extension

So I am working on a Google Chrome Extension that takes a screenshot of the current tab and sends the base64 string of the screenshot to the content script. The code below is the source of the content script. My problem is that when I try to display the screenshot on the canvas nothing appears. the `response` variable is where the base64 string is. For debugging purposes i logged the string to the console to make sure it works and it does it fact return a string.

**Console**

[image]

**Content Script**

```
    $("body").append('<canvas id="myCanvas" width="315" height="205" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({actions: "screenshot"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
        img.src = response;
    });
```

Comment: First check: Does it work if you set the image src to a “normal” URL, instead of a data URI?

Comment: @CBore ok yeah that's not even working either.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? There's a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245296) in Chrome 27, 28 and 29 that makes the `Image` constructor unreliable. Try to use `document.createElement('img');` instead.